# How can I echo with escaped spaces?

Tags: bash, echo, printf

I want to echo a variable with spaces into a text file.

```
a=a\ b\ c
echo $a > /tmp/a
```

The above results in a file with `a b c` in it. What if I need the file to read `a\ b\ c`?

I've tried `printf %q $a` but that doesn't seem to do what I want either.

Note: Also assume that I don't produce the content of `$a` it is passed to me outside my control. I just need to make sure it is saved with escaped spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Backslashes escape the next character; in your case, you've escaped the space, at which point the contents of `$a` become: `a b c`. If you want the contents of $a to have backslashes, then you need to escape them:

```
a=a\\\ b\\\ c
```

or

```
a='a\ b\ c'
```

---

If $a already contains text with spaces and you want to save it to a file, simply:

```
printf "%q" "$a" > /tmp/a
```

When you ran:

```
printf "%q" $a > /tmp/a
```

You told printf to quote *3* split & globbed pieces of text: `a`, `b`, and `c`, which it dutifully escaped (doing nothing) before being redirected into /tmp/a as `abc`.

Take a good read through: [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/117549) to see what's going on.

Comment: What if I want to convert a variable where spaces aren't escaped to one where they are? For example `$a` is simply random text but it needs to be saved with escaped spaces? Should I run grep and replace spaces with `\ `?

Comment: Maybe something like `echo $a | tr ' ' '\ ' > /tmp/a`?

Answer (score 1):

Just put it in quotes.

```
a="a\ b\ c"
```

Alternatively, escape the escape.

```
a=a\\\ b\\\ c
```

Both end up with the same result.

Comment: Thanks but my question is about how to print the output. I don't actually have control of setting the contents of `$a` in my situation. I just need to print it out with escaped spaces.

Comment: How does it come in?

Answer (score 1):

Solution based on feedback from Jeff:

```
echo $a | sed -e "s/ /\\\ /g" > /tmp/a
```

Comment: You should really quote `$a`